# Word or phrase that everyone knows or has heard of, but no one knows its underlying meaning

Tags: word-usage, expressions

What word or phrase can describe terms like:

- Wi-Fi
- AM/FM
- AM/PM
- RSVP
- "etc."
- "i.e."

and so on? In other words, what word or phrase could be used to describe a word or phrase that "everyone knows the word, but no one knows what it means/stands for/*et cetera*?"

Comment: Except for *Wi-Fi*, all of those words actually do have an underlying meaning. *Wi-Fi*, however, never stood for anything else [when it was coined](https://www.howtogeek.com/259000/what-does-the-fi-in-wi-fi-mean/). It simply was what it was, despite some people's attempts to ascribe meaning to it after the fact. (Who assume it means *wireless fidelity*. Except that it doesn't.)

Comment: +1. I interpret this question as asking for a word that covers abbreviations that have become so commonly used that *an ordinary person* might not know what the original expanded version is. We EL&U contributors are of course so knowledgeable that we know all of them, but let's find the word that the rest of the English-speaking world might find useful...

Answer (score 1):

Anachronisms

Which means ‘words belonging to a different period’.

The origin of which, (some!) people have either forgotten about or don’t know about.

I suggest this, as most of the words you mentioned come from an earlier time such as ‘id est’ and different languages such as French ‘repondez s’il vous plait’ or latin ‘et cetera’. Words of a ‘forgotten origin’ or ‘out of their time’.

As such they are ‘anachronistic’ which is from ‘ana’ - backwards and ‘khronos’ - time.

Little words which are having a teeny timewarp moment.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anachronism

Comment: Thanks so much! So these are "anachronistic phrases"?

Comment: You’re welcome, @El Ectric - yes, anachronistic phrases, or you could also say that they are ‘anachronisms’. As in ‘the term RSVP is an anachronism - few now know its origin’.